# Redis server starts behaving erratically and stops functioning properly. Causing other services to malfunction

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, redis

I have a docker-compose file with 4 containers, one of which is Redis. The image builds up properly and runs properly initially but after some time (sometimes it happens within 10 minutes or sometimes after a few hours) the Redis start throwing errors and my container 'worker' fails.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    command: gunicorn EmotAPI.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: emot_web
    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
    command: python manage.py rqworker default
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web

  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

**redis error log** (after which functions start to fail)

```
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:53.556 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:53.556 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:54.567 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:54.567 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:56.509 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:56.509 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk: Invalid argument
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:56.870 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:56.870 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:57.588 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:57.588 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:58.581 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:58.581 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:59.596 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:03:59.596 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:00.612 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:00.612 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:01.609 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:01.609 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:02.613 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:02.613 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:03.613 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:03.613 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:04.631 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:04.631 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:05.624 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:05.624 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:06.625 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:06.625 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:07.653 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:07.653 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:08.658 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:08.658 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:09.648 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:09.648 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:10.659 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:10.659 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:11.674 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:11.674 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:12.670 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:12.670 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:13.665 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:13.665 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:14.686 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:14.686 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:16.669 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:16.669 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk: Invalid argument
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:17.056 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:17.057 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:17.692 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:17.692 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:18.709 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:18.709 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:19.716 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:19.716 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:20.712 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:20.712 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:21.717 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:21.717 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:22.731 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:22.731 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:23.732 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:23.732 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:24.743 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:24.743 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:25.739 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:25.739 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:26.740 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:26.740 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:27.751 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:27.751 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:28.752 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:28.752 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:29.768 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:29.768 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:30.775 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:30.775 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:31.772 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:31.772 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:32.761 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:32.761 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:33.796 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:33.796 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:34.794 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:34.794 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:36.756 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:36.756 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk: Invalid argument
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:37.126 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:37.126 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:37.811 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:37.811 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:38.813 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:38.813 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:39.821 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:39.821 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:40.818 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:40.818 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:41.832 # Failed to read response from the server: Connection reset by peer
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:41.832 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:42.830 # Failed to read response from the server: Operation in progress
1:S 06 Jul 2022 08:04:42.830 # Master did not respond to command during SYNC handshake
```

I am unable to find a solution for it. Also, I am quite new to Redis so sorry if it's just a silly question, but there were no resources available so I had to resort to asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was not with Redis actually but a security issue. You shouldn't really open the ports to the public. Cryptojackers were taking control of the redis server and causing it to malfunction. To fix it, I just had to remove the line 'ports: - "6379:6379"' and the issue was resolved.